# How to make this SQL query faster

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like

table1:

```
word id
a    1
a    2
a    10
c    20
d    21
e    30
```

table2:

```
id1 id2
1 20
2 21
```

Now if word=`'a'` then I need to find out `'c'` and `'d'` using table1 and table2:
I wrote a query, its working but taking too much time, because tables include huge data.

Query:

```
SELECT word 
FROM table1 
WHERE id IN 
        (SELECT id2 FROM table2 
         WHERE id1 IN 
                  ( SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE word = 'a'))
```

Another query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE word = 'a')
```

Comment: could you show us the query?

Comment: Could you write down your query to see whats slow.

Comment: Show us a code. Also I recomend to post questions like this to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: And do you use indexes on tables?

Comment: I edited with my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.WORD
FROM TABLE1 T1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID2
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 T3 ON T2.ID1 = T3.ID
WHERE T3.WORD = 'a'
```

You should always try to avoid using nested `SELECT`s and use `JOIN`s as much as possible. This is because there is an order in which statements are executed inside a query.

`JOIN`s always execute before `WHERE` statements and by doing this you're filtering one step earlier.

If `JOIN`s can't solve all your problems, than you can put conditions in your `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great,could you please look at my another query i Used like the first one.

Comment: @android The correct way would be to post another question about this, give a link here and then I would answer.

Comment: Please check this out

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this but.  Check that you have indexes on your id's

```
select word 
from  table1 where id in (
select table2.id2 
from Table1 inner join Table2 on id1 = Table1.id and Table1.word = 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT word 
FROM table1 WHERE id IN(
                         SELECT table2.id2 
                         FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON id1 = Table1.id AND Table1.word = 'a'
                       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this also...

```
SELECT  t.word
FROM    table1 t
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON t.id = id2
        INNER JOIN table1 tt ON id1 = tt.id
WHERE tt.word = 'a'
```

Comment: @android when you use `In` in select query then your query performance always goes down. So to improve your performance use `Inner Join`.